# "for" loop for reading line from a file is not working

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to read file from bdata.txt. Here it is opening file properly but not start for loop, you can see attached screen where it is not printing log3 and but prining confirmation about file opening. Below is the code. Please advise

```
####### get file name
#fname = input("Bike Data File name: ")
try:
    fh = open('bdata.txt')
except:
    print("Not able to open file")

print(fh)
print("Log2")
counter=0
####### extract data
for line in fh:
    print("Log3")
    counter = counter+1
    print(stripped_line)
fh.close()
print(counter)
print ("**********EOF***********")
```

[image]

Comment: What is the actual contents of the file you open? Are you sure you open the correct file?

Comment: You have to print line instead of stripped_line I would say

Comment: You read `line` but never do anything with it.

Comment: Your code should `NameError` at `print(stripped_line)` because `stripped_line` is never defined. Problem not reproducible.

Comment: Please learn about [the `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) which will simplify parts of your code.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using `with open() as` when working with files like this.

```
with open("bdata.txt", "r") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        # perform file operations
```

Where does your `"print(stripped_line)"` variable for this come from as it doesn't seem to have been declared in your example?